# Регулярное выражение: минимум одна буква верхнего регистра

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html5, input

```
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]{4,}[0-9]{4,}$">
```

не могу понять, как изменить регулярное выражение, чтоб получить условие минимум одной буквы верхнего регистра, не обязательно **ПЕРВОЙ**.

Comment: Цифры и буквы нижнего регистра тоже должны присутствовать? С случайном порядке, или в том, который указан сейчас в регулярном выражении?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поле пароля: минимум 8 символов, одна цифра, одна буква в верхнем регистре и одна в нижнем

```
^(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Взял [отсюда](https://htmlweb.ru/html/form_input_pattern.php).

Comment: Врете в описании регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Извините меня за  некорректно сформулированный вопрос. Задача была такова: пароль должен состоять из минимум 8 символов, 4 из которых цифры, 4 буквы (минимум  одна  верхнего и минимум одна нижнего регистра). 
Получилось так. Спасибо за советы!

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}(?=.*\d).{4,}$
```

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение бред! https://regex101.com/r/jW1rL7/1 Кто интересно его заплюсовал?

Answer (score 0):

```
"^.*[A-Z]+.*$"
```

Означает "Начало строки, любой символ 0 или больше раз, большая буква 1 или больше раз, любой символ 0 или больше раз, конец строки".

Выражение, **точно** соответствующее поставленной задаче:

> условие минимум одной буквы верхнего регистра

**UPD.** Как верно заметил Нумминорих,

> в целом, можно было бы сократить до `"[A-Z]+"`, ну и если нужно -
>   добавить русские буквы

Comment: в целом, можно было бы сократить до `"[A-Z]+"`, ну и если нужно - добавить русские буквы